# Combine 2 VARRAYS Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a function that returns an Array of codes (NUMBER).

```
select GET_USER_OFFICE_CODES(10) FROM DUAL;
--output--
DB.OFFICE_CODES(3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

and

```
select GET_USER_OFFICE_CODES(2) FROM DUAL;    
--output--
DB.OFFICE_CODES(1,10,14,21)
```

In a function I am trying to combine 2 ARRAYS of the same type.  I get an error "wrong number of types of arguments in call to 'MULTISET_UNION_ALL'"

```
create or replace function COMBINE_OFFICE_CODES(
  in_local_office_code NUMBER,
  in_regional_office_code NUMBER
)
RETURN OFFICE_CODES
IS
  local_office_codes OFFICE_CODES;
  regional_office_codes OFFICE_CODES;
  combined_office_codes OFFICE_CODES; 
Begin
  local_office_codes := GET_USER_OFFICE_CODES(in_local_office_code);
  regional_office_codes := GET_USER_OFFICE_CODES(in_regional_office_code);
  combined_office_codes := local_office_codes MULTISET UNION ALL regional_office_codes;

  RETURN combined_office_codes;
end
```

Comment: "Multiset" operators work on multisets (obviously), which in Oracle are called "nested tables". They don't work on arrays (varray in Oracle). An array is an ORDERED sequence of values; there is no concept of "union of **arrays**". Do you really need arrays there, or can you change to nested tables? That would make the most sense. If you really do need arrays, that can also be arranged - it's a bit more complicated, and you need to specify what order you want in the UNION. (And, again, if your answer is "order doesn't matter", then *you don't need arrays*, you need nested tables).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Changing the TYPE to TABLE did the trick.                   
 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OFFICE_CODES AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

Answer (score 3):

You can use UNION ALL;

```
create type OFFICES_CODES is varray(100) of number;

declare
  local_office_codes OFFICES_CODES := OFFICES_CODES(1,2);
  regional_office_codes OFFICES_CODES := OFFICES_CODES(3,4);
  combined_office_codes OFFICES_CODES; 
Begin

  SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO  combined_office_codes FROM  
  (select *from table(local_office_codes) 
    UNION ALL  
  select *from table(regional_office_codes));
 
 FOR i in 1..combined_office_codes.count loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(combined_office_codes(i));
 end loop;
 
end;
/
```

> Statement processed. 1 2 3 4

*************EIDT *********

You can also get rid of local variables and use directly functions.
Try this:

```
create or replace type OFFICES_CODES is varray(100) of number;

create or replace function  get_office_codes (nNum number) return OFFICES_CODES
is
vRet offices_codes;
begin
    if nNum = 1 then
        vRet := offices_codes(1,4);
    else
        vRet := offices_codes(3,6);
    end if;
    return vRet;
end;
/


declare
  combined_office_codes OFFICES_CODES; 
Begin

  SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO  combined_office_codes FROM  
  (select * from table(get_office_codes(1)) 
    UNION ALL  
  select *from table(get_office_codes(2))
  ORDER BY 1);
 
 FOR i in 1..combined_office_codes.count loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(combined_office_codes(i));
 end loop;
 
end;
/
```

Comment: This approach doesn't make a lot of sense. "Array" means that the order is important. The array in your solution will have random order of elements. Even if you try to fix that, it's not clear it's even possible; it is unknown if the TABLE operator will generate the elements in array order. In some simple examples that seems to be true, but it's definitely NOT documented. On the other hand, as I told the OP already, if order is not important then he shouldn't be using arrays in the first place.